# Yamaha fz700 handlebar bent

Tags: yamaha, throttle, handling

Bike got tipped over by a random person, handlebar got bent, and throttle is really hard to move now so I decided to try to take it out to see what I could do. Here is a picture of the bar:

[image]

You can see where it's bent, and I wanted to know is there any easy way to unscrew the bar to take it and get it unbent, or should I just unscrew it and replace the whole bar at the fork

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but would bet your best option is the last one. I know straightening tubes of any sort is a *very hard option*. There should be an Allen head bolt which is clamping to the forks. You don't want to take the fork loose if you can help it, as getting alignment back right could be a huge pain in the butt for the uninitiated. If replacement is not an option, I'd suggest you find a very large vise and heat the bar until you can bend it back into shape. I doubt it would ever get completely straight again, but you could get it pretty close. Your easiest/cheaper option would be to find one online from someone who is selling parts. Though this may be one of the first things which would go.

Comment: So the Allen head bolt would be the one that releases the bar? I didn't wanna take the nut off and everything, knew it would probably cause some Alignment issues. I'm going tomorrow to the parts store to see what they have, if there's nothing I may just have to try straightening it. Thanks for the assistance though

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to take that off.
Can't see from your picture, but usually there's one or two clamp bolts and maybe a positioning bolt running vertically (maybe from the triple clamp area to the clip on mount)  After this it looks like you can just take it off the top of your fork.

IF the only damage in that area is the bend (see possible vertical bolt mentioned before)  You might try bending it back yourself, if there's no kinks in the tube and the bend isn't bad.

Otherwise i'd be looking to wreckers for a spare, or maybe even a set of after market ones (replacing left & right so they are the same)

To help with your searching.... you're looking for a "clip on"... handle bars normally go from left to right, whereas the clip on (which you have) is clamp bolted to the top of the fork.